# Nhibernate query

Tags: nhibernate

I have a class like this:

> ```
> Class ItemCategory
> Item
> Category
> ```

I would like to select all (distinct) Items base of the intersection between two disjunctions of CategoryIds. Is this possible using the criteria api?

Thanks.

Best wishes,

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate doesn't support Unions. You would need to use native SQL.